# IOleCommandTarget.QueryStatus: SaveAs command is supported but not enabled

Tags: com, infopath

I have been using `IOleCommandTarget.Exec()` to execute the `SaveAs` command successfully on InfoPath forms. However, it is failing on a client machine because `IOleCommandTarget.QueryStatus()` only returns a value of `OLECMDF_SUPPORTED`. To use the command, it needs to be both `OLECMDF_SUPPORTED` and `OLECMDF_ENABLED`.

What could be causing the command to be not enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the command was not available was because File -> Form Options -> Filler Features -> “Save and Save as” was unchecked on the form.

[image]